# Convert Wordpress shortcodes into plain html

Tags: shortcode

I am building a static landing page on WordPress root folder, and I need to import some shortcodes from an existing page located in `wp-content` directory.

What I do is import with `$post = get_post($post_id)` the post containing my shortcode, then I extract it ->

> $output = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

Finally I do ->

> echo do_shortcode($output);

The issue here is that on the page I got displayed only the raw format of the shortcode, like `[shortcode]`;

There is a way to convert shortcodes into plain html so my page can display it correctly or I am missing some `require/include` somewhere?
I already added `define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); require "wp-load.php";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other who wonders about it: I resolved adding  `WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes()`; to my function, which renders all shortcodes!

> ```
> define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
> require_once "wp-load.php";
> require_once "wp-content/themes/salient/functions.php";
> ```

```
/*
Function that gets an object containing post data
and returns in output the post_content value.

Return string.
*/
function get_post_content(){

    //renderize shortcode
    WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();

    $post = get_post(INSERT_POST_NUMBER);
    $output = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
    $value = do_shortcode($output);
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a syntax error. If your shortcode is stored in the `$output` variable, you would need to call `echo do_schortcode($output);`.

But, wouldn't simply `the_content();` do the trick? I believe the shortcodes would be processed if you do this.

You can make a new query with [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), and then use `the_content()` in the loop.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post', // This selects only posts
  'post_status' => 'publish' // Only published posts
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
    <?php }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: I update my question, that was a typo :) 
however, where should I place the_content()? I am totally new to wordpress, even id I know that is a basic wordpress function I would like to know where to place it in my code

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if that works for you.